# Классификации HTML-макетов

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как называется HTML-макет динамически варьирующий свою ширину в определенных пределах: т.е. при разрешении 1024х786 — ширина 900px и не уменьшается, а при разрешении 1280х1024 — 1100px и больше не увеличивается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Типовые макеты](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety)

> Различают пять типов макетов, связанных с шириной:
>
> - фиксированные;
> - резиновые;
> - эластичные;
> - адаптивные;
> - комбинированные.

Comment: То бишь по данной классификации это таки резиновый макет. Спасибо.